# Is there a more declarative GUI approach for C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

*(TODO rephrase the title, if we find a more accurate term for what I'm about to describe)*

I'm learning .NET and I have noticed that most GUI features (specifically Windows Forms and WPF) are designed with the workflow around designing the GUI visually and bringing it to life using event handlers, inspired by Borland Delphi.

Having worked with Java and Eclipse technologies before (such as JFace nad the commands framework), I have become used to another approach, which I could sum up as:

- create logic objects such as:

  - commands (specifying its behaviour and metadata such as name, icon, help string),
  - data models (specifying its access methods);
- use the infrastructure to automatically create the GUI parts for the above, as in:

  - "create a button from this command",
  - "create a menu option from this command in all popups for object type XYZ",
  - "create a tree viewer for this data source"...

Etc.

I favour this approach as it allowed to me to separate logic and display while not requiring me to write too much boilerplate, such as event handlers for individual controls.

Are there similar facilities for .NET that you could recommend?

Comment: @downvoter, please explain thyself and inform me what's wrong with my question so that I can correct it and ask better questions in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may checkout [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) and the [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Gue what - read the documentation. of a newer version of .NET.

MS with Windows Vista or 7 added the WPF based libraries (.nET 3.5) which use a XAML based approach. With some extensions (which are totally in line with what it is prepared to do out of stock) you pretty much do the whole UI without programming, hooking commends and handlers (methods) in the XAML part.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't XAML like 20 python lines away from corresponding C# code? Don't I write the same thing, but with less `()` and more `<>`s?

Comment: Nope. WPF XAML Code is basically a persistnece of a graphph of objects - with objects also being hooks to methods and such. It is optimized for separating design (state of objects) from programming of said objects.